# If I pray to G-d to make a certain women to become my wife, will G-d be able to make that happen?

Tags: quran

If I pray to G-d to make a certain women (whom I met, known since long a time ago, Muslim women, chaste AFAIK and not married yet) to fall in love with me (even though she has a boyfriend but not yet married) or to become the one whom I will spend the rest of my life with, will G-d be able to make that happen?

Which verses of the Quran supports the claim that G-d has the ability to make a person to fall in love with you or which verses support that the matter of who will become your wife is in the G-d's Hands?

Regards,

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Do not use comments for answering questions. If you have an answer, post it as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you believe in an almighty, all-seeing, personal god, yes, of course.

Now what if the woman prayed too? What if she prayed to fall in love with another man? Whose prayer should be heard?

What if I consider you all-powerful and all-seeing, from an ants point of view? 
You could see where the small ant is going, what food it is going to pick up and where it is going to take it.
You could just do its work for it.
But you might starve another anthill from its food.
Instead of doing work for hundreds of little things for individual ants, would you not be more interested in watching it all play out?

Comment: Thx but I was asking something else....for reassurance